# How to create .exe from .jar where external libraries are included?

Tags: java, launch4j

I used launch4j to create .exe from my .jar. I mentioned the custom classpath where I selected my main class and the other libraries were seen below.

I created the .exe but the libraries are not working when I launched the exe.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: you may go through this [http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse]

Comment: you should post you error log , in order for people to help you

Comment: Thank you for the concern but It was a small error and I have solved it.. :)